# Is there a way to view the man pages in color in emacs?

Tags: eshell

I am trying to read the `man` pages in color. So far I have been using `eshell` and just typing `man <program>` However this does not use color to highlight the options etc.

I have read that `M-x woman` mode will render the `man` pages in color.

However not only does this fail to render the pages in color, usually it does not work at all or it shows the pages not in color (which is what the `M-x man` command does).

Is there a way to render the man pages in color?

Comment: Assuming that you're already able to view man pages in color inside your bash console; inside your emacs, launch `M-x term` then, within term, `man <program>`?

Comment: Good idea. I was hoping there was a more built in way

Comment: Man pages don't have colors, only bold and italics. Do you see things in bold and italics (or underline)? If so, that's all there is. If not, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Customize man's faces ?

Answer (score 10):

Add the follows to your init file and use `M-x man` or the `man` command in eshell to view man pages: (the colors fits the `wombat` theme; you can change them for yourself)

```
(require 'man)
(set-face-attribute 'Man-overstrike nil :inherit 'bold :foreground "orange red")
(set-face-attribute 'Man-underline nil :inherit 'underline :foreground "forest green")
```

Or to be theme agnostic:

```
(require 'man)
(set-face-attribute 'Man-overstrike nil :inherit font-lock-type-face :bold t)
(set-face-attribute 'Man-underline nil :inherit font-lock-keyword-face :underline t)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What should I do to applu this to `woman`?